# Accuracy values are missing while applying KNN on Iris data using caret package in R

Tags: r, knn, caret

Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
getting this error while applying k-nn on iris data.
''' iris.knn<- iris

```
# Dividing data into test_train
set.seed(532)
sample.iris.knn <- sample.split(iris.knn, SplitRatio = 0.8)
train.iris.knn <- subset(iris.knn, sample.iris.knn== TRUE)
test.iris.knn <- subset(iris.knn, sample.iris.knn == FALSE)
dim(train.iris.knn)
str(train.iris.knn)
head(train.iris.knn)
# fitting K-nn model
set.seed(8237)
trControl.iris.knn <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                                    number = 10,
                                    repeats = 3)

iris.knn.model <- train(Species ~., data = train.iris.knn,
                        method = 'knn',
                        trainControl = trControl.iris.knn,
                        preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                        tuneLength = 13)
# Model check
iris.knn.model
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no argument in the function `train` named `trainControl` , it is `trControl` so change it will solve your problem

```
iris.knn.model <- train(Species ~., data = train.iris.knn,
                        method = 'knn',
                        trControl = trControl.iris.knn,
                        preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                        tuneLength = 13)
```